# How to decrease adc accuracy?

Tags: arduino-uno, adc

I read in this [atmega328p datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf) the following on page 308:

From sect. 28.4:

> By default, the successive approximation circuitry requires an input
> clock frequency between 50kHz and 200kHz to get maximum resolution. If
> a lower resolution than 10 bits is needed, the input clock frequency
> to the ADC can be higher than 200kHz to get a higher sample rate.
>
> The
> ADC module contains a prescaler, which generates an acceptable ADC
> clock frequency from any CPU frequency above 100kHz. The prescaling is
> selected by the ADC Prescaler Select bits in the ADC Control and
> Status Register A (ADCSRA.ADPS). The prescaler starts counting from
> the moment the ADC is switched on by writing the ADC Enable bit
> ADCSRA.ADEN to '1'. The prescaler keeps running for as long as ADEN=1,
> and is continuously reset when ADEN=0.
>
> When initiating a single ended
> conversion by writing a '1' to the ADC Start Conversion bit
> (ADCSRA.ADSC), the conversion starts at the following rising edge of
> the ADC clock cycle.
>
> A normal conversion takes 13 ADC clock cycles.
> The first conversion after the ADC is switched on (i.e., ADCSRA.ADEN
> is written to '1') takes 25 ADC clock cycles in order to initialize
> the analog circuitry.

By required bandwidth is 120 kHz, and 5 bit accuracy will suffice for my purpose. So, I understand that I can achieve this by changing the prescaler to a lower division number, thus increasing the clock frequency fed into the ADC (as per the diagram in the aforementioned document).

However, the document only specifies the min and max times required for ADC conversion for 50 kHz (12 to 280 microseconds at 50kHz bandwidth).

My question: Given my requirement of 120kHz bandwidth, what is the lowest prescaler division value I should use to guarantee ADC completion time to within 1/120kHz seconds (8.3us)?

EDIT: This is another question I have: Why does the accuracy change when using a lower divider value? Surely we are simply changing the clock frequency fed into the ADC converter, not the ADC algorithm itself; so why should the bit accuracy change?

Answer (score 2):

From: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=6549.0

The documentation states that 13 cycles are neccesary for ADC conversion. Thus, using the clk/13*8 divisor configuration, and 16 MHz system clock, the upper bound becomes 154KHz

The forum post in the above link continues to say that "ADC clock frequencies above 1MHz are uncharacterised", however this was quoting another document for which the link is dead. I could not find this statement in the most recent documentation.

Edit: Another forum post where a user successfully used an atmega328p to achieve 360000 samples/sec, so it is technically possible:
http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=8795.0

Comment: Nick Gammon [did some tests with various prescaler values](https://www.gammon.com.au/adc), and the data at prescaler = 8 shows errors as large as 17% of the full scale.